# HTML/CSS div tags not working properly

Tags: html, css

I am making a website (from scratch) for a school project. I am intending my website to have one column for a title, 3 columns for the info and one bottom row for additional info, but instead it looks like a big mess. ie:

### Title

Info1 Info2 Info3

Footer

I have replaced the info with Lorem Ipsum.

I have made a JSfiddle which can be viewed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jm3p7moj/).

My HTML looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-content">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="about">
                <h3>About Me</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ut lorem enim. Fusce ac varius ante. Mauris consequat, nibh viverra finibus consequat, erat mauris porttitor risus, id cursus nisi nunc id massa. Nullam imperdiet scelerisque lorem eget luctus. Nullam massa magna, luctus sit amet tellus vel, viverra ultrices velit. In commodo luctus odio ac tincidunt. Nullam feugiat erat tincidunt, cursus odio eu, accumsan lacus. Nunc sit amet tellus elementum, vehicula magna vel, feugiat tellus. Nullam et lorem iaculis lorem imperdiet commodo. Nulla facilisi. Etiam pulvinar vulputate auctor.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="school-life">
                <h3>School Life</h3>
                <p>Nam in quam euismod, sollicitudin arcu in, posuere erat. Phasellus ligula justo, efficitur quis odio eget, faucibus mollis sapien. Cras mi ipsum, sagittis ac orci porttitor, porta rutrum ipsum. Donec at libero molestie, venenatis eros et, faucibus lectus. Nullam ex enim, aliquam in tellus vel, porttitor egestas est. Nunc fermentum nisi justo, in ultricies arcu ornare sit amet. Duis nunc nulla, semper et libero ut, pulvinar condimentum sem. Aenean non eros id libero consectetur venenatis id nec magna. Fusce quis risus iaculis, tempus lectus eu, posuere nulla. Donec vitae posuere est, nec pellentesque elit. Phasellus mollis orci vel ex dignissim, sit amet pellentesque mauris luctus. Suspendisse eget dapibus sem.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="favourites">
                <h3>My Favourites</h3>
                <p>Aenean libero erat, pharetra sed feugiat id, tempus quis nulla. Donec a mi quam. Aenean nisl neque, blandit at scelerisque ac, finibus sit amet tellus. Fusce nec eros ac nulla suscipit molestie. Donec imperdiet nunc ac diam dignissim consectetur. Etiam malesuada cursus tellus, volutpat dignissim metus laoreet non. Etiam id quam hendrerit quam varius blandit vel consequat ex.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hopes">
                <h3>Hopes for the Future</h3>
                <p>Proin eget condimentum turpis. Mauris elementum at nisi nec condimentum. Donec maximus diam sapien, eu rhoncus erat volutpat quis. Nulla tortor felis, tincidunt id sagittis vel, laoreet in erat. Nunc ultricies sed tellus sit amet faucibus. Nulla molestie justo id odio molestie aliquam. In fermentum diam in sapien molestie porttitor.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS is:

```
.container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
.title {
    width:auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.main-content {
    display: block;
}
.about {
    width: 333px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    float: left;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: inline;
}
.school-life {
    width: 300px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    float: center;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: inline;
}
.favourites {
    width: 333px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: moccasin;
    float: right;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: inline
}
.hopes {
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated ty

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jm3p7moj/1/ fiddle with only the relevant html

Comment: Do you need two about me?

Comment: Akshay, you my fiddle in the comments, I think he messed up the copy/paste, he even had two <head> tags

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jm3p7moj/2/

I won't explain what I did 'cause there was too much going on. Just read about css floats (you had float: center; which is not valid css), overflow ( I use it to clear float), clearing floats.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This just tells the browser that for every element, the padding goes inwards.

Comment: You probably meant `box-sizing` instead of `box-sigin`